# FTP Publishing for an existing website

Tags: iis

How can i set up a FTP Publishing for an exiting website ? I followed this tutorial http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/303/adding-ftp-to-a-web-site/ but it dosen't work. I'm not able to acces ftp.ip.port from browser. I can't also acces from ftp.domain.tld. I don't know what i do worng

Comment: I've made a "new rule" with port 20 and 21 so i guess it's ok.

Comment: OK as in it works now?

Comment: it was always that rule with 20 and 21 ports and it dosen't work

Comment: any ideea ?????

Answer (score 0):

Start with these steps:

- ping the name (ftp.domain.tld or whatever you used) to ensure that it resolves to the correct IP if your server
- from the ftp server itself, telnet test (from the command line: telnet {ip address} 21)
- if that works, test FTP from the local machine and see if the connection is established
- test from another computer and see if the result changes.  If it does, then it's firewall related.

This will let you know if it's something prior to FTP or if it's the FTP settings itself.

What error do you get when it fails?